# Partition free space wont merge

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

After successfully removing the page file from my partition allowing me to delete the volume,the partition drive is now considered a free space. But I'm unable to create simple volume if thats what im suppose to do in order to extend volume of my main partition. The extend volume option isnt in use either so what do I do?.

[image: http://prntscr.com/e822e6]
[image: http://prntscr.com/e82382]

Comment: If my answer for deleting the page file helped why not accepting the answer?

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to extend the other partition the space needs to be **Unallocated** and not merely **free space**.

For that to happen you need to right-click the free space (as you did in the first screenshot and press **Delete Partition**.

After finishing that you'll be able to extend the other partition into this unallocated space.